# How to convert drawable.draw(canvas) to canvas.draw(bitmap)

Tags: android

How to convert call

```
Drawable someDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
someDrawable.draw(canvas);
```

to `canvas.draw bitmap` ?

I am trying to used buffered bitmap and speed up drawing.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not clear. Are you trying to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?

Comment: @StevenTrigg Yes, I want to convert Drawable to bitmap and then draw on the same place where did I draw with call someDrawable.draw(canvas)